# How to handle authorization token in encrypted response body and pass that token to the subsequent requests in JMeter

Tags: node.js, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, onlinebanking

handle authorization token in encrypted response body and passed to the subsequent requests

encrypted data in response body decrypted using the code send by the developer , in that decrypted body authorization token that we need to handle and stored inside a variable and pass to the next requests.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by my own.
-->First I store the encrypted response body in variable using regular expression extractor
--->Then I used beanshell preprocessor and call the variable which includes encrypted response body and decrypted it using the code send by the developer and stores that decrypted data in variable
--->copy that variable in dummy sampler response body
--->Now I used the regular expression extractor and extract the AUTH token and saved in variable and passed it to the subsequent requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform decryption using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language.

Response body can be accessed like:

```
String body  = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
```

once you do the decryption you can either substitute original encrypted response with the decrypted response like:

```
prev.setResponseData('decrypted-response-here', 'UTF-8')
```

or save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
vars.put('decrypted-response, your-decrypted-response)
```

More information on what do these [`vars`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) and [`prev`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) mean: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

You may also find [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) blog post useful